# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.gobblin.runtime.cli.GobblinCli

Tags: java, build.gradle, gobblin

I am new to gobblin. I build gobblin from incubator-gobblin GitHub master branch. Now I am tring wikipedia example from getting started guide but getting following error.

`WARN: HADOOP_HOME is not defined. Gobblin Hadoop libs will be used in classpath.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.gobblin.runtime.cli.GobblinCli`

with `--show-classpath` it gives `/mnt/c/users/name/incubator-gobblin/conf/classpath::`
How can I solve it? Please let me know if anyone know the solution.

Comment: can you please post the link of the example you are trying, just so others can try or verify if the example is complete or not

Comment: wikipedia example  https://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-Started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you run this command in `incubator-gobblin/build/gobblin-distribution/distributions/gobblin-dist` and not in `incubator-gobblin/gobblin-distribution`